# loop through every list

Tags: python, list, date, loops

I have lines of list generated for every input line read from a logfile 
I would like to loop through every list and parse the date attribute bit of list  please do provide your suggestions

```
listgen  = line.split() 

['2013-07-23T14:08:17.111906+01:00', 'server24', 'status=inprogress', 'MSG= Transfer Intitated']
['2013-07-23T14:08:26.630043+01:00', 'server x2', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response']
['2013-07-23T14:08:27.188360+01:00', 'server35', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response']
['2013-07-23T14:08:27.306438+01:00', 'server35x', 'status=successful', 'MSG= Transfer Completed']
['2013-07-23T14:08:27.342922+01:00', 'serverx56', 'status=inprogress', 'MSG= Transfer Intitated']
['2013-07-23T15:12:10.803993+01:00', 'server267', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response']
```

I want to loop through every list and parse the date attribute in the list

```
for i in listgen:
    #print [i:]        
    dat_e = parser.parse(listgen[0])
```

expected output :

```
2013-07-23 14:08:17.111906+01:00
2013-07-23 14:08:26.630043+01:00
2013-07-23 14:08:27.188360+01:00
2013-07-23 14:08:27.306438+01:00
2013-07-23 14:08:27.342922+01:00
2013-07-23 15:12:10.803993+01:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Uh...

```
for i in listgen:
    #print [i:]
    print i[0].replace('T', ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in listgen:
    date = item[0].replace('T', ' ')
    print date
    #do other things with date
```

Comment: That should be `replace('T', ' ')`, but otherwise, this makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

Assuming:

```
listgen = [['2013-07-23T14:08:17.111906+01:00', 'server24', 'status=inprogress', 'MSG= Transfer Intitated'],['2013-07-23T14:08:26.630043+01:00', 'server x2', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response'],['2013-07-23T14:08:27.188360+01:00', 'server35', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response'],['2013-07-23T14:08:27.306438+01:00', 'server35x', 'status=successful', 'MSG= Transfer Completed'],['2013-07-23T14:08:27.342922+01:00', 'serverx56', 'status=inprogress', 'MSG= Transfer Intitated'],['2013-07-23T15:12:10.803993+01:00', 'server267', 'status=waiting', 'MSG= waiting for response']]


for i in listgen:
    print i[0] # that's your date part
```

You can apply whatever function you want (like parse etc. ) to it.

Comment: when im  trying to do as above I get only the 1st digit of date from list ie 2

Comment: @user2667326 Here Im assuming that listgen is a list of all lists. If its not, then please mention the value of listgen in the question.